# Detecting the login type of the user

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using Django-AllAuth for 3rd party account logins.

Currently, I activated Facebook and Google logins. That let users to login to my system with one of the following 3 ways.

1. Using Django login form
2. Using Facebook login
3. Using Google login

If a new user logins first time with a 3rd party OAuth provider, I got user information from the related service and create a user record with a *non-usable* password.

My question is, is there any way to recognize how the user had logged in (using default login or a 3rd party OAuth tool) so I can display that info anytime while the user is logged in?

I know that I can write a `logged_in` signal to capture the data and store it is somewhere. But I am wondering is there any existing way to get this info.

Comment: I was looking at these areas for other reasons and have done some hunting; I believe that there is no existing mechanism either in allauth or in common circulation as an add-on patch. I would recommend going ahead with the logged_in signal handler approach.